# Adding TTL on edges/ vertices doesn't work on Mixed index(elasticsearch version > 6.x.x)

Tags: janusgraph

I'm using janusgraph with AWSKeyspace (cassandra) and elasticsearch as the storage and indexing backends respectively. I have a requirement to delete all the edges older than 30days. Setting a TTL on edge/vertex property doesn't work on mixed index.

Elasticsearch version used is 7.x.x. I think elasticsearch stopped supporting ttls after 6.x.x onwards and now it is a part of index life cycle management which janusgraph doesn't support as of now(v0.6.2)
Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/mapping-ttl-field.html

Should we be handling this outside of janusgraph for now? If there is any other way please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This confusing behavior has been an open issue since 2018, see:
https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/987

Therefore, the issue predates the elasticsearch 6.x to 7.x upgrade and does not seem related to this. Also, no alternatives are suggested other than using solr as an indexing backend for JanusGraph.

Comment: Interestingly elasticsearch 5.x.x did support ttl feature https://www.elastic.co/blog/ttl-documents-shield-and-found.